# How determine if a partial list and a larger list with all of the partial lists' elements, are in the same order?

Tags: python-2.7

e.g. [a,a,c,e] and [a,b,c,d,e]. This is what I mean by same order. It shouldn't matter if one of the lists is only partial. To be clear, I am uninterested in sorting anything.

Edit: Apparently I should mention that I mean lists with some different values. e.g. [a,a,c,e] and [a,b,c,d,e] are in the same order. Simply getting rid of duplicates and cutting the bigger list won't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit the different values requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first getting the unique elements from partial list `a` (in the order of `a`), then get those elements from full list `b` (in the order of `b`). Then you can compare the two and see if they are identical.

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 4, 3]
>>> a = sorted(set(a), key=a.index)  # Remove duplicate elements, but keep the original order
>>> a
[1, 4, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
>>> b = [x for x in sorted(set(b), key=b.index) if x in a]  # Get unique elements of a from b in order of b, and filter them out to get only elements present in a
>>> a == b
True

>>> a = [4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> a = sorted(set(a), key=a.index)  # Remove duplicate elements, but keep the original order
>>> b = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
>>> b = [x for x in sorted(set(b), key=b.index) if x in a]  # Get unique elements of a from b in order of b, and filter them out to get only elements present in a
>>> a == b
False
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to squash identical consecutive items into a single item of that value.  We can then `zip` together the squashed values with the other list to see if they are the same

```
from itertools import izip, groupby

def  squash(iterable):
    return (k for k, _ in groupby(iterable))

def same_order(iterable, reference):
    return all(x == y for x, y in zip(squash(iterable), reference))


print(same_order((1, 2, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
# True
print(same_order((1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first take the unique set of b, then truncate to the size of a (or vice versa)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5]

a == list(set(b))[:len(a)]
```